# Informix using a subquery

Tags: sql, informix

i have an Informix DB V11.*.

It has a Table like this.
(It is no Unique Field given)

```
DATE       |TIME     |NUMBER |STATUS |INFO
2015-01-09 |10:00:00 |123456 |A      |Bla
2015-01-10 |09:00:00 |123456 |300    |Blu
2015-01-10 |07:00:00 |123456 |100    |Foo
2015-01-09 |03:00:00 |123456 |A      |Bla
2015-01-10 |11:00:00 |123456 |C      |Baa
2015-01-10 |14:00:00 |123456 |Q      |Bla
```

Now i have to find the STATUS and INFO  of the
Record with the latest DATE and TIME.

It is NOT the Problem to get the MAX Value of 
the latest record (in this case the record with the time "14:00:00")

The problem is, to get the STATUS and INFO field, according to the "14:00:00" record.
So that i can retrieve a result like this:

```
STATUS |INFO
Q      |Bla
```

This query will be used, as subquery, so it hast to return ONE row, maybe concatinated.
Causing the using as **Subquery**, i can´t use SKIP 0 FIRST 1.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably this is what you want:

```
select first 1 *
from table t
order by date desc, time desc;
```

The problem is that you cannot use this as a subquery *unless* it is the in `from` clause.  A simple way to accomplish this is something like:

```
select . ..
from (select first 1 *
      from table t
      order by date desc, time desc
     ) first1 cross join
     . . .
where . . .
```

Then you can use `first1` in the rest of the query.